Fix for "ITMS-90863: : Macs with Apple silicon support issue - The app links with libraries that aren’t present in macOS: libswiftCloudKit.dylib"
some weeks ago, I first received this error message from App Store Connect when uploading a new version of my app.

ITMS-90863: Macs with Apple silicon support issue - The app links with libraries that aren’t present in macOS:
/usr/lib/swift/libswiftCloudKit.dylib

Problem is: On my side, there were no changes (at least no changes to the project - XCode version and macOS version have changed since then, but the error occurs even if I compile the project with on older version). Oviously, this leeds to an incompatibility flag in the App Store, so my app is not available on the Mac App Store.
What I've tried so far:

Removed the LSMinimumVersion key from info.plist. Also tried several version numbers.
Tried several macOS deployment targets under Targets > Deployment > macOS Deployment Target
Removed the libswiftCloudKit entry from Targets > Build Phases > Link Binary with Libraries
List the libnswiftCloudKit entry from Targets > General > Frameworks

None of these helped. I am stuck. And I am getting into trouble because I should release an update to my app but I can't because the Mac version would not be offered.

Verify that the produced binary (or any embedded dylib/framework) doesn't have mentioned link with otool -l . Look for load command name under each LC_LOAD_DYLIB  e.g. otool -l /System/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/MacOS/Calendar

This is becoming an increasingly common issue that appears to be on Apple's side.  I've got an outstanding support ticket with them that the engineering team is investigating and there is a thread on the Apple Developer Forum as well.  https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/766061?answerId=810185022#810185022

@StuartW great you filed a support ticket. That's what I was just about to do also. Here's another thread concerning this: link Please be sure to post any reactions you get from Apple here!

I never received a response from Apple, but it appears they've fixed the problem.  Just successfully submitted a new build and all back to normal.
